# Key is returning 'None' instead of value in sqlite3dbm

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have to create a code using sqlite to create database using dictionaries. For that I have imported sqlite3dbm. When I run the testscript it is not accepting keys and is displaying 'None' as key values. I want the method getID() to be executed. Any suggestions to retrieve the key value. Code is as follows:

```
import sqlite3dbm
from sqlite3dbm.dbm import *
import os

class sqlite1():
    def __init__(self, pa, na, rq):
        self.dbname = None
        self.name = None
        self.id1 = 0
        if rq == 'open':
            print(pa, na)
            self.hdl = sqlite3dbm.dbm.open(os.path.join(pa, na), 'open')
            if not b'id1' in self.hdl or not b'ns' in self.hdl:
                print("open")
            try:
                self.id1 = int(self.hdl[b'id1'])
                self.name = self.hdl[b'ns']
            except:
                pass

        else:
            self.hdl = sqlite3dbm.dbm.open(os.path.join(pa, na), 'c')
            self.id1 = 0
            self.hdl[b'id1'] = str(self.id1)


    def getID(self):
        return self.hdl[b'id1']


    def setID(self, id1):
        self.hdl[b'id1'] = id1
```

Testscript is:

```
from stackoversq import *
from stackoversq import sqlite1


class Test1:
    def __init__(self, pa, na, rq):
        self.pa = pa
        self.na = na
        self.id1 = 0
        self.abc1 = sqlite1(pa, na, rq)
        self.abc1.setID(0)

    def fileopen(self, pa, na, rq):
        self.abc1 = sqlite1(pa, na, rq)

        if (b'0' == self.abc1.getID()):
            print("getSRD_ID() is True")
        else:
            print("getSRD_ID() is False")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tst = Test1('', 'file.db', 'c')
    tst.fileopen('', 'file.db', 'open')
```

Comment: Please respond to my post

Comment: Does any one can help out